# TypeError when passing bytearray to C++ extension

Tags: python, c++

Python code:

```
image = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/test.png').read()
bytes = bytearray(image)
print [myext.do_stuff(bytes, mode=1)]
```

C++ code:

```
static PyObject * 
do_stuff(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
   PyByteArrayObject *imgdata;
   char *image;
   int mode;
   char *keywords[] = { "image", "mode", NULL };

   if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "O|i", keywords, &imgdata, &mode))
      return NULL;

   image = PyByteArray_AsString((PyObject*) imgdata);
   char *result = do_something_more(image, mode);
   return Py_BuildValue("s", result);
}
```

Added:

```
char * do_something_more(char imagebuffer[], int mode)
{
  vector<char> vec(imagebuffer, imagebuffer + sizeof(imagebuffer));
  Mat input = imdecode(vec, 1);
}
```

Comment: What's the full traceback you get? AFAIK the code is correct. Are you sure you are using an up-to-date build of the extension?

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must be impossible<bad format char>, not bytearray

If I change "Y|i" to "O|i" then I don't get that error. But then strlen(image) is always 8 instead of the actual size.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with the correct version of python? AFAIK the `Y` format character was introduced in python3 (since `bytearray` was introduced in that release). Maybe you are linking with the python2 interpreter instead, which cannot recognize it. The `impossible <bad format char>` error is raised by `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` when it cannot recognize the format character (see the sources under `Python/getarg.c`).

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and linking against 2.7. I didn't realize Y was only for 3.0, sorry. I am just looking at passing the image buffer to C++ where it's stored in a char*. Do I need to convert it to a bytearray first or is there a better way?

Comment: I think the only way to pass around a `bytearray` in python2 is to use the `O` format character...

Comment: I used O and it accepts it. But after that when I use image = PyByteArray_AsString((PyObject*) imgdata) and check the strlen of image, it's always 8, not the actual size. Updated it with more code and sample output. I'm not sure if the bytearray was not parsed correctly, or if something went wrong during conversion to string.

Comment: Using `Y` wouldn't change that. In fact you can look at the source code and you'll see that using `Y` *only* checks for the type of the argument. It does *not* do any kind of conversion. Also note that the string printed in the example output *is* 8 bytes in length: `\x89`, `P`, `N`, `G`, `\r`, `\n`, `\x1a`, `\n`.

Comment: Why is it limited to 8 though? Is it because of a null character somewhere in there? Shouldn't it be the whole image? The sample image that I used is 85861 bytes. How do I get the whole thing?

Comment: Did you check whether the `image` in your python script contains the whole image? I have no idea why shouldn't read the whole thing...

Comment: Yes, I did check the image and it's the whole thing. I just opened up the image in a hex editor and there are two null characters after 8 bytes. So I tried changing them and now the size is 16 (another null character at that point), so my char* is getting cut off. What other variable type should I be using?

Comment: The problem is that `urlopen` reads *text*. Since null characters usually denote the end of text the data is cut off. You may try to explicitly tell how many bytes to read (like: `.read(1000)`).

Comment: len(image) in Python is showing the correct size. It's when it goes to C++ that it's getting cut off. There has to be some way to pass this raw data to C++? I think it's getting passed to C++ correctly but the problem is is probably when I use PyByteArray_AsString(). I need to convert it to something that I can use with opencv's imdecode().

Comment: Oh my God, we are idiots. `strlen` returns the length of a *C string*. So actually, even in C++, you *have* all the data available, simply  `strlen` sees the `\0` and stops before reaching the real length. The returned value cuts off the string for the same reason...

Comment: I fixed it with int image_size = PyByteArray_Size((PyObject*) imgdata);

Answer (score 2):

The typeerror is simply due to the fact that the `Y` format specifier does *not* exist in python2 but only in python3. If you want to pass a `bytearray` in python2 you must use the `O` format specifier.

The fact that the result string is just the first few bytes of the actual contect is pretty simple:

- `strlen` is a C function that deals with C *null terminated* strings. Your image data contains some null bytes and hence the function does *not* return the *actual* size.
- [`PyBuild_Value`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue)'s `s` format specifier takes a C *null terminated* string and returns a python string object. Since your data contains null bytes not all the content is put  in the result.

In your C++ code the `char *image` pointer *does* point to *all* the data, but you should *not* rely on C's string functions if your strings contain null bytes. You must always keep track of the length of the string.

---

To make clearer what I mean. Here's a self-contained C extension that can be used to demonstrate your problem:

```
#include <Python.h>


static PyObject * 
do_stuff(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
   PyByteArrayObject *imgdata;
   char *image;
   int mode;
   char *keywords[] = { "image", "mode", NULL };

   if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "O|i", keywords, &imgdata, &mode))
      return NULL;

   image = PyByteArray_AsString((PyObject*) imgdata);
   return Py_BuildValue("s", image);
}

static PyMethodDef noddy_methods[] = {
    {"do_stuff",  do_stuff, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Does stuff"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};

void
initdemo(void) 
{
   (void) Py_InitModule("demo", noddy_methods);
}
```

With `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('demo',
                    sources = ['demo_ext.c'])

setup (name = 'Demo',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

Used as:

```
>>> import demo
>>> with open('/Path/to/A/PNG/Image.png', 'rb') as f:
...     contents = f.read()
... 
>>> byt = bytearray(contents)
>>> byt[:20]
bytearray(b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02V')
>>> demo.do_stuff(byt)   # "truncates" the data
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'
```

Now if you change the `do_stuff` function to:

```
static PyObject * 
do_stuff(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
   PyObject *imgdata;
   char *image;
   int mode;
   Py_ssize_t length;
   char *keywords[] = { "image", "mode", NULL };

   if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "O|i", keywords, &imgdata, &mode))
      return NULL;

   image = PyByteArray_AsString(imgdata);
   length = PyObject_Length(imgdata);
   PyObject *res = PyString_FromStringAndSize(image, length);
   return res;
}
```

You get:

```
>>> import demo
>>> with open('/home/giacomo/Immagini/bad_grouping.png', 'rb') as f:
...     contents = f.read()
... 
>>> byt = bytearray(contents)
>>> byt[:20]
bytearray(b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02V')
>>> demo.do_stuff(byt)[:20]
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02V'
```

As you can see `do_stuff` does *not* truncate the data anymore.

All functions such as `strlen` assume no null byte is in the string and will misbehave when this is not true (as in this case). Also some python's API calls assume C strings, such as `Py_BuildValue`. As you can see the `char *image` **does** contain *all* the data. The problem is that you are using functions that don't handle it properly.

Comment: Even when I use a vector and try to load it with imdecode(), it says the PNG buffer is incomplete.

Comment: @Crypto Check what `sizeof(imagebuffer)` returns. AFAIK, at least in C, using `char x[]` is the same as `char *x`. To verify this try to explicitly add, for example, `1000` and see whether the result contains 1000 bytes.

Comment: I asked someone about this. He said on a 64 bit OS, sizeof() will always return 8 for a char array. Instead I used PyByteArray_Size((PyObject*) imgdata) to get the real size. This fixed the problem.